# Wordpress CPT Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I've registered custom post types and placed each under it's own subdirectory. That works fine but if I click on the subdirectory itself, it returns a 404. My question is how do I register the subdirectory as a template. I've tried creating a page template for that slug but unfortunately, that specific directory isn't registered. Here's what I've done:

```html
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {

$postNames = array('NZ-Music', 'Movie-Reviews', 'NZ-Fashion', 'Fashion-Trends', 'Beauty-Tips', 'Beauty-Products', 'Beauty-Trends', 'Gift-Ideas', 'New-Restaurant', 'Restaurant-Review');

foreach ($postNames as $postType) {

$lowerCase = strtolower( $postType );
$replaceSpace = str_replace("-", " ", $postType);

  register_post_type( $postType, 
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( $replaceSpace ),
        'singular_name' => __( $postType )
      ),
      'taxonomies' => array('category'),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-' . $lowerCase,
      'rewrite' => $postType . "/" . $postType,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => $postType . "/" . $postType,
    )
  );

 }

}
```

For NZ-Music, the uri would look something like this: /nz-music/post
and that will return the post. But when I try search only /nz-music, this returns 404. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`archive-{post-type}.php` is the answer.